# I am looking for a JSON query to format Currency column in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting, column-formatting, currency-field

I am looking for a JSON query to format Currency column in SharePoint Online. Below query works but removes currency icon from the value.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "background-color": "yellow"
  },
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

Comment: Are you formatting Currency column? Is it working on currency column?

Comment: Please see this URL. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types Based on that column formating is not supported for currency column.

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of your field on which you are adding this JSON?

Currently Column/JSON Formatting will support only following column types:

**Supported column types:**

The following column types support column formatting:

- Single line of text
- Number
- Choice
- Person or Group
- Yes/No
- Hyperlink
- Picture
- Date/Time
- Lookup
- Title (in Lists)

**The following are not currently supported:**

- Managed Metadata
- Filename (in Document Libraries)
- Calculated
- Retention Label
- **Currency**

**Reference:**

1. [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types).

**Work Around**:

If you want to concatenate currency symbol to numeric columns then you can use below JSON:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "background-color": "yellow"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "$",
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-block",
        "padding": "0 1px"
      }
    },
    {
      "elmType": "span",
      "txtContent": "@currentField"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Reference**:

[Concatenate Currency Symbol to Numeric Columns](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/column-samples/currency-symbol-concatenation).

---

**Update**:

Currency column is now supported in SharePoint JSON formatting (it was not supported when original question was asked).

You can get the value of currency column in JSON column formatting  using:

```
"txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue"
```

**Or** by using internal name of currency column (for view formatting):

```
"txtContent": "[$MyCurrencyColumn.displayValue]"
```

Where `MyCurrencyColumn` is internal name of your currency column in SharePoint list. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Are you using number or single line of text field? and you want to concatenate currency symbol??

Comment: FYI, per Anoop's answer, this seems to get the original currency value, including dollar sign and commas:  `"txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue"`

Comment: Yes, it was not supported when original question was asked. I have updated the answer accordingly now.

Answer (score 1):

For currency field you can try:

```json
"txtContent": "@currentField.displayValue"
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint JSON formatting - displayValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#displayvalue)